# Retrieve HTML from a different HTML page using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code in my **update.html** page :

```
<td>Latitude: 48.837750828462205</td>
<td>Longitude: 2.5585527265625387</td>
```

I would like retrieve these two latitude/longitude values (48.837750828462205 ; 2.5585527265625387) in another HTML page called **map.html**.

How can I do this in JavaScript?

Comment: What have you tried? Do you host the update.html page?

Comment: You would need a central database for both files, a server or localStorage

Comment: What do you mean by "recover"? Create a new map.html which only consists of these two number (while updade.html is larger)? create a new map.html whic among other things contains these two numbers? Create a map.html which will show these numbers from the current version of updade.html at the time when map.html is accessed? From identical server? From other server? In any case please provide a (tailored) sample input and desired output (either quoting the resulting map.html, or otherwise define the desired resulting look).

Answer (score 1):

The simplest answer to your question would be the following.

in your `update.html` page.

```
    <td id="latitude">Latitude: 48.837750828462205</td>
    <td id="longitude">Longitude: 2.5585527265625387</td>
    ....
    .... After your </body>

    <script> 
      localStorage.setItem('latitude', document.getElementById('latitude').innerText.split('Latitude: ')[1]);
      localStorage.setItem("longitude", document.getElementById('longitude').innerText.split('Longitude: ')[1]);
    </script>
```

in your `map.html`

```
     <td id="latitude"></td>
     <td id="longitude"></td>    
     ....
     .... After your </body>

     <script>
        document.getElementById('latitude').innerText = 'Latitude: ' + localStorage.getItem('latitude'); 
        // You get the Latitude, Longitude values stored in 
        // localStorage here.
        document.getElementById('longitude').innerText = 'Longitude: ' + localStorage.getItem('longitude');
     </script>
```

Although I agree this is the simplest solution to your problem it may surely not be the only one or the optimal one. You could also save these values in your server database and fetch them using [axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios) or AJAX. You could also use a client-side database like [PouchDB](https://pouchdb.com/) or [RxDB](https://github.com/pubkey/rxdb) to sync values across multiple browsers at the same time and you don't need a server to begin with.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple solutions
- store the information inside a database (with an AJAX call)
- store the information inside localstorage / sessionstorage
- send the information inside the url as a GET param

Answer (score 0):

If the latitude and longitude are not generated dynamically, the easiest thing to do would just be to hard-code them as variables in *map.html*.

With the assumption that they are dynamic, you can use [XHR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) or the more modern [`fetch` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) to get *update.html* and then parse it with [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) and query the DOM to get the values.

I would add `id`s to the elements so that they are easy to find in the DOM:

```
<td id="lat">Latitude: 48.837750828462205</td>
<td id="long">Longitude: 2.5585527265625387</td>
```

Then, in *map.html* you could do something like this:

```
let url = 'update.html';
let req = new Request(url);
fetch(req).then(res => {
    let stripLabel = text => {
      return +text.match(/\d+\.\d+/)[0];
    };
    res.text().then(htmlSource => {
      let parser = new DOMParser();
      let doc = parser.parseFromString(htmlSource, 'text/html');

      let lat = stripLabel(doc.getElementById('lat')),
        long = stripLabel(doc.getElementById('long'));

      console.log(lat, long);
    })
}).catch(err => console.error(err));
```

The [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) `/\d+\.\d+/` in `stripLabel` matches the number and then the [unary `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_()) before the `return` statement converts the matched text into a number.

**Also see:**

- [Fetching data from the server](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Fetching_data)
- [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#Arrow_functions)
- [ES6 In Depth: Arrow functions](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/06/es6-in-depth-arrow-functions/)